# Method overloading in java regarding arguments with int/long and String/object

Tags: java, overloading

For the following program why the methods with int and String arguments are getting called instead of long and Object?

Wanted to know why the compiler is choosing int over `long` and `String` over `Object` arguments.

Note: This was asked in an interview.

```
public class MethodOverloadingTest {

    public static void add(int n, int m){
        System.out.println("Int method");
        System.out.println(n+m);
    }

    public static void add(long n, long m){
        System.out.println("Long method");
        System.out.println(n+m);
    }

    public static void method(String st){
        System.out.println("from String method");
    }

    public static void method(Object obj){
        System.out.println("from Object method");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add(2,3);
        method(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Rafa El's comment got an upvote, but it's wrong. The compiler does not pick the first method that it finds; it picks the most specific method that fits the arguments. Try putting the methods in a different order in the class, and you'll see that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe it was up-voted because it is funny.

Comment: It's not "funny", it's just wrong.

Comment: Then the most specific method will be picked. Look it up in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) if you want to know the exact rules.

Comment: Oh! Now I remember i've actually learn it during high school!. shame on me.

Answer (score 5):

For the `add(2,3)` method, you are passing integers, that's why integers are getting called. 
For `method(null)`, the most specific method argument is chosen. In this case, `String` is more specific than `Object`. Hence `method(String st);` gets called.

Comment: Nop that’s not the complete and totally correct answer which the interview must be looking for..

Comment: @Khay I guess you already know the answer and you're testing all of the people here.

Comment: Yep - use add(2L,3L); to call it with Longs or method((Object)null) :]

Answer (score 1):

The concept is called as Early Binding. Most specific method (based on arguments) is Chosen at compile time.

`Object` is the least specific than any other class in java, Since it is the super class of all.

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

How it chooses is given in rule set, Specified here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Its simple because Java treats number by default as int and letters as string object , not as generic objects .

so when you pass add(2,3) , its taking the arguments as the normal int

to call the add(long  , long) pass the arguments as  ;  ***add(2.0,4.0)***  something like this . and for calling the function method(object)

1.first typecast your string to type object
String str;
str= (object) "Hello world";

2.and then pass to method(str);